# Automated database history save and recovery Drupal 7

Tags: 7, database

I have a site implemented in Drupal 7. I want to make a history database recovery tool, which will recover previously recorded MySQL data. I have tested correctly on non-Drupal content which is used by the site. If I want to recover previous versions of Drupal content (just nodes and the info related), should I use a collaboration module? Which would be recommended? Should I restore the complete database or could I mysqldump and later mysql some selected tables (fields*, node*, etc.). Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Backup & Migrate Module:](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate)

> Back up and restore your Drupal MySQL database, code, and files or
>   migrate a site between environments. Backup and Migrate supports gzip,
>   bzip and zip compression as well as automatic scheduled backups.
>
> With Backup and Migrate you can dump some or all of your database
>   tables to a file download or save to a file on the server or offsite,
>   and to restore from an uploaded or previously saved database dump. You
>   can choose which tables and what data to backup and cache data is
>   excluded by default.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have installed and tested the module, and it seems very complete. However, I miss some features, for example, making incremental backups.The site has thousand of images, and I only need to backup once and then make differential changes when individual files are deleted, updated, uploaded. I was not able to find anything similar in the advanced backup settings of the contributed module.

Comment: I don't believe it has that feature, so if that's a deal breaker, you might have to look at a 3rd party backup option, using any server provided backup options, or write something custom to suit your specific needs